# Search for certain values in Textfile and convert them to string

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How do I read multiple values from a textfile and convert those to a string in order to modify them.
For Example I have TESTUSER.txt

```
Max Mustermann Kuerzel: MMUSTERMANN reads books
He lives in GERMANY
10 years ago he lived in POLAND
His Phone number is 0123456
His best friend was Peter, peter@testmail.com
His new best friend is Joseph, Joseph@example.com
```

I need the values GERMANY, POLAND, 0123456, Peter, peter@testmail.com, Joseph and Joseph@example.com.
The format of the text is always the same, the only values that change are the ones that are given above.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you come up with so far and where did you get stuck? Regular expressions might be of help or splitting on a per line-basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this pattern:

```
with open('t.txt') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

for line in lines:
    if line.startswith('He lives in '):
        location = line.replace('He lives in ', '').strip()
```